# PHP/SQL assign sql result to session

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to assign a value from a query result to a session but it isn't working..

**Session username**
below, i am registering the session username which is the users email

```
$_SESSION['myusername'] = $myusername;
```

**check login**
Here i am trying to get the customer name from the same table were the email is stored and save it in the "name" session

```
$_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];
```

**Logged success**
here i am trying to fetch the user's name

```
echo "Welcome ". $_SESSION['name'];
```

**check login page***

```
<?php
ob_start();
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="xx"; // Mysql username 
$password="xx"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="xx"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="customer"; // Table name
$db_usercol="email"; // Field containing username
$db_passcol="password"; // Field containing password

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form 
$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE $db_usercol='$myusername' and $db_passcol='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

if($count==1){
// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "profile.php"
session_register("myusername");
session_register("mypassword");
$_SESSION['myusername'] = $myusername;
$_SESSION['name'] = $row['name']; 
header("location:profile.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

**on successful login***

```
<?
// Check if session is not registered , redirect back to main page. 
// Put this code in first line of web page. 
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION[$myusername])){
header("location:members.php");
}
else
include("header.php");
?>

<body id="profile">
<div id="wholewrap">
<div id="bodywrap">

<div id="content">
<h1>Your Profile</h1>

<?php

echo "Welcome ". $_SESSION['myusername'];
echo "Welcome ". $_SESSION['name'];
?>

</div>  <!-- content #end -->

<div id="sidebar">

Lorem Ipsum

</div>  <!-- sidebar #end -->

</div>  <!-- bodywrap #end -->
</div>  <!-- wholewrap #end -->

 <?php include("footer.php"); ?>
```

**The result is**

I only get the username but not the name of the user, which is a field in the same table named *name*

[image: result]

Comment: Do you have `session_start()` on both pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to have a query, something like this

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `name` FROM `users` WHERE `email`='".$_POST['email']."'") or die(mysql_error()); // of course you want to clear the strings and validate them
```

then you do

```
if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0)
{
   $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

   $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks i was missng the `$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);`

Comment: what does the mysql fetch assoc do?

Comment: Returns an associative array that corresponds to the fetched row and moves the internal data pointer ahead.